# Is it possible to make call from apple watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am working on the push notification ; can I have an action button in the dynamic interface which will call or  msg a number displayed in the UI- means a random mobile number?

I ma using xcode 6.4 and watch os 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WatchOS 2 its possible.

```
if let telURL=NSURL(string:"tel:5553478") {
    let wkExtension=WKExtension.sharedExtension()
    wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```

I think it has to be a real number you want to call, so you have to replace it.

Comment: Thanks but this  can't use in xcode version 6.4-requires 7? Is there a way to do it in xcode 6 itself? i cant update the watch OS to 2

Comment: I´m sorry but you can´t get Xcode 7 without a developer account (I think you can get WatchOS 2 with the public beta of iOS 9 but there is no point without Xcode 7) You have to wait for the official version which is normaly published in september.

Comment: Does it mean we cant do this in WatchOS 1 and xcode 6.4?

Comment: Yes. You need WatchOS 2 and Xcode 7